# JSONField reference a model like One to One within the JSON

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-jsonfield

Stupid question time! :)

I don't think this is possible but I need to ask in case I'm wrong. Is it possible to create a one to one relationship to a normal Django model in the JSON of a `JSONField`?

Example:

Django Model (Example):

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    example = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    something = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
```

Django model in separate app (Example):

```
class JsonModel(models.Model):
    json_stuff = JSONField(default=list)
```

The JSON itself will be a list of dictionaries of will have multiple layers but some need to hold a reference to the `TheModel` to be presented in a template (the same way a One to One relationship would).

JSON (Example):

```
[{"title": "A Title", "body": [{"line": "Some text", "reference": TheModel}, {"line": "More Text", "reference": None }]}
```

It's looking like I'll have to loop through the JSON and insert the reference manually in the view.

**Edit**

Following on from @ruddra's comment. There is no consistancy in which `TheModel` is referenced. If there was I would have made a normal One to One relationship.

Please note that I'm asking if it's possible not what I need to do. I am already putting the id of `TheModel` where it needs to go I'm only curious to see is `JSONField` can do One to One in the same why Django does `ForiegnKey` fields in templates.

Comment: No, it's not possible in a high-level way, you just need to set the value to `themodel_instance.id` directly. Note that there's no "looping through the JSON" if you're using a `JSONField` you can access its properties directly as in any python `dict`.

Comment: If you have consistency in json with the reference for the `TheModel`, then why don't you try to make it a FK with null True, so that it can be null able as well.

Comment: @rudda Each reference will be to a different 'TheModel' int the database.